# ¿Por qué debo implementar IDisposable en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

No termino de entender el uso de `Dispose` en C#, tengo entendido que sirve para eliminar los objetos pero no me acabo de entender cual es su uso, ya que creo que C# dispone de un recolector de basura automático.

> Edit: He estado buscando mas información y se utiliza para los recursos no administrados, pero cuales son los **administrados** y **no  administrados**?

Answer (score 6):

El uso de **dispose** tiene una utilidad mayor en el caso de los recursos no administrados, pero cuál es la diferencia entre un recurso administrado y uno no administrado?

### Recursos administrados

> Se refiere a todos los tipos dentro de .NET a los que el garbage
> collector tiene acceso y de los que se encarga de "administrar",
> administrar los recursos que utilizan (uso de cpu y memoria). Aquí se
> incluyen todas las clases del Framework .NET.

---

### Recursos no administrados

> Se refiere a aquellos que existen fuera del sandbox de .NET que
> incluye cualquier cosa que es devuelto a través de llamadas a las API´s
> Win32, que son la manera de acceder a las API´s nativas del sistema
> operativo.

---

### Pero...

Si tú nunca llamas a una función en el API de Win32 y nunca obtienes ningun Win32 "handle" object, entonces tu no estas manteniendo ningún recurso no administrado, pero los **Files,Streams, conexiones a base de datos,etc** que tu abres a través de las clases del .NET framework son wrappers(envoltorios) administrados. Tú podrías no mantener ningún recurso no administrado directamente, aun así tu podrías estar manteniendo indirectamente a través de wrappers administrados, es por eso que los wrappers administrados implementan **IDisposable**.

### Dispose y IDisposable

Te permiten deshacerte de cualquier recurso que tú hayas obtenido del sistema operativo a través de .NET (recursos no administrados) y liberar de esa forma objetos que estén usando recursos.

Es imperativo que se liberen los recursos después del uso de cualquier recurso no administrado (usado directa o indirectamente), por esta razón seria común ver en .NET fragmentos de código como el siguiente.

```
try
{
  MemoryStream Mem = new MemoryStream();
  //Trabajamos con el y luego
}catch{}
finally{
  if(Mem!=null)Mem.Dispose();
}
```

Pero para evitarnos repetir este código siendo tan necesario el liberar recursos no administrados en .NET, con la interfaz IDisposable podemos hacer uso de la sintaxis **using**, que nos permite escribir el fragmento anterior de una manera más elegante.

```
using(MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
{
   //Trabajamos con el y luego se llamara a dispose automaticamente
}
```

**Recuerda implementar IDisposable en las clases que tu hayas construido, las cuales mantengan referencias a recursos no administrados o wrappers administrados.**

Comment: Es que estoy mirando este ejempo http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection pero cuando se llama a dispose del public class ProductRepository : IDisposable?

Comment: Casi al final dice "Web API then calls GetService on the child scope to create the controller. When request is complete, Web API calls Dispose on the child scope. Use the Dispose method to dispose of the controller’s dependencies." , se refiere a que al registrar el product repository con el IoC container el se encarga de hacer dispose de los objetos creados cuando la request ha finalizado.

Comment: no cabe duda, el buen @JesusAngulo regresó enhorabuena a StackOverflow en Español :D #LlamemosAtodosLosMsInfluencers! el gran maestro Mauricio Sougarret también anda por estos lares :D

Answer (score 2):

El Dispose se utiliza para cerrar o liberar correctamente sentencias que crean subprocesos en el sistema operativo, como por ejemplo la clase MemoryStream.

En la actualidad, se utiliza la sentencia using para utilizar el Dispose de forma desacoplada, por medio de la interface IDisposable. Ejemplo:

```
 using (MemoryStream MEM = new MemoryStream()) 
 {
 }
```

Utilizándose de esta forma, el objeto MEM solo existirá dentro de los paréntesis de llave. Cuando el cursor de ejecución salga de dichos paréntesis, la sentencia using se encargará de cerrar correctamente los recursos del sistema utilizado por el objeto MEM, y no solo eso, sino que también todo objeto creado dentro de los paréntesis de llaves.

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

El método Dispose se implementa para liberar recursos no administrados que la aplicación usa.
[Implementing a Dispose Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx)

[IDisposable – The oft misunderstood and misused interface](http://reedcopsey.com/series/idisposable/)

El using es una muy buena practica para definir objetos que necesitas liberen sus recursos una vez que terminas de trabjar con ellos.

El using asegura una correcta destruccion del objeto, ya que solo sera valido dentro de la region que lo define.

se usa bastante el using para definir objeto de conexion de ado.net

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("conn string")){
   conn.Open();
   //resto del codigo
}
```